# In Javascript, what is considered "computationally expensive"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, optimization, react-hooks

I have been learning about wrapping initial state values in callback to implement Lazy Initialization of useState hooks in React. It is a cool trick, but every resource or tutorial is a bit vague or opaque in regards to how to determine something is computationally expensive.

I know that I shouldn't wrap a primitive in a callback e.g. `() => 0` or `() => ''` as this would actually be worse as the cost to create this callback outweighs just using the primitive every time. But it is unclear at what thresh hold do I need to cross before the expression becomes expensive. Is `someArray[someIndex]` expensive? is `'foo' + 'bar'` or `1 * 1` expensive? I know `window.localStorage.getItem('fizz')` and `Math.random()` are expensive, but only because these were used as examples in addition to the useless `expensiveComputation()`.

If there is no clear "hard line" to cross that can be used as a rule to answer this question, are there any tools or debugging techniques that can be used to decide?

Comment: Question belongs here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Measure performance with and without the hook, compare, decide.